# Quickly attach common files in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to quickly attach a specific file (or even better, have a list/quick options) to an email?

I get asked to send a template I have a few times a week.  Instead of having to attach by browsing my computer, going through the folders to get to it, is there a quicker way?  If I've attached it recently, it's in recent files; but most times it's not in the recent list.

Unfortunately I can't use VBA to solve it (I could add a quick macro to attach the file), is there a way to somehow "pin" common files for quicker attaching?

One solution would be create an email template, but I'd rather find a way to simply attach the file so I can do so in a reply/thread.

Comment: Create a shortcut to the folder containing the file on the desktop? (Not sure if a shortcut to the file itself would be useful.) Open folder; drag and drop...

Comment: @Hannu - Not a bad idea. Certainly an option if no in-Outlook method is available.  Thanks!

Comment: According to my experience, there's no option except macro that could meet it in Outlook, so agree with Hannu, simple drag and drop may also be a good choice.

Comment: @Jade yeah that's what my experience is telling me too. I was hoping to find something like a Quick parts entry you can use with attachments. Hm

Comment: I usually work with vba or template in this case, if you wouldn't like them and do need a quick part function to attach file in Outlook, I suggest you post your idea in outlook uservoice: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: @Jade thanks for the suggestion. I'd usually use VBA but it's a work computer and it seems VBA on outlook is reset every time outlook is restarted.